# Function decorator raising positional argument error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators

I'm trying to write a function decorator that tests for bounds of x, y

```
#this is my bound test function
def boundtest(func):
    def onDecorator(self, x, y, *args, **kwargs):
        print(x, y, *args, **kwargs)
        assert x in range(self.width) and y in range(self.height)
        return func(x, y, *args, **kwargs)

    return onDecorator

class Game:
    #these are the functions that need bound checking

    @boundtest
    def at(self, x: int, y: int) -> int:
        return self.map[x, y]

    @boundtest
    def set(self, x: int, y: int, data):
        self.map[x, y] = data.value
```

When I execute `game.set(1, 1, Color.RED)` I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Projects\bubble-breaker-bot\game.py", line 61, in <module>
    game.set(1, 1, Color.RED)
  File "C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\Projects\bubble-breaker-bot\game.py", line 21, in onDecorator
    return func(x, y, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: set() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'
```

I need the boundtest function to check if `x` and `y` are in range of `self.width`, and `self.height` respectively while being able to pass an arbitrary amount of parameters to the function it is decorating.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decorators are applied to function objects, not to bound methods. This means you need to *pass on the `self` argument manually*:

```
def boundtest(func):
    def onDecorator(self, x, y, *args, **kwargs):
        print(x, y, *args, **kwargs)
        assert x in range(self.width) and y in range(self.height)
        return func(self, x, y, *args, **kwargs)

    return onDecorator
```

Python uses a process called *binding* to turn a function into a bound method, and calling a bound method automatically passes in whatever it is bound *to* as the first argument; this is how `self` is passed into a method when you call a fuction on an instance. See the [*Descriptor HowTo*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) for details. Instead of manually passing on `self`, you could [invoke descriptor binding manually](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors), by calling [`func.__get__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) to produce a bound method:

```
def boundtest(func):
    def onDecorator(self, x, y, *args, **kwargs):
        print(x, y, *args, **kwargs)
        assert x in range(self.width) and y in range(self.height)
        bound_method = func.__get__(self, type(self))
        return bound_method(x, y, *args, **kwargs)

    return onDecorator
```

That binding behaviour was applied to the `onDecorator` function object your decorator returned when `game.set` was being resolved, but not to the wrapped `func` object.

Comment: @heemayl: I added the usual exposition with links to the documentation.

Comment: Is there a better way to go about writing a decorator? Following PEP 20 the zen of python "Simple is better than complex. Flat is better than nested." the nested function seems a bit obnoxious if you ask me.

Comment: @BenjaminKosten: Not sure why you think that. A decorator is expected to return either the original function or a replacement object. The easiest and simplest way to produce a replacement that re-uses the original is by using a nested function object that then has access to the original as a closure. The added advantage is that the produced function object is unique; you can and should use [`@functools.wraps(func)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to copy across identifying information. And decorators greatly help make the rest of your code simple!

Comment: @BenjaminKosten: however, you could take a look at the [`decorator` project](http://decorator.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) if you feel that that would produce clearer code for you.